# R loop not looping through days

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have this code that should iterate through each object in "days." However, when I run the loop it only returns the dates found on the last day.

```
days = seq(as.Date("2004-09-21"),as.Date("2004-09-25"),by = 1)

for (i in days){
  
  link = paste0("https://alrai.com/search?date-from=", days[i])
  
  readlink <- read_html(link)
  link_maxpagenumbers_full <- readlink %>%
    html_elements(".roboto-b") %>%
    html_text2()
  link_maxpagenumbers_cut <- str_extract_all(link_maxpagenumbers_full,'\\d{1,3}')
  
readlink <- read_html(link)

article_links <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".font-700") %>%
  html_attr("href")

link_title <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".font-700") %>%
  html_text2()

link_date <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".size-13")%>%
  html_text2()

link_pagesummary <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".size-14") %>%
  html_text2()
  }

alrai <- data.frame(article_links, link_title, link_date, link_pagesummary)
```

I'm genuinely not sure why - I imagine this is suppose to return a link for each day, and article_links for each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is going through all of the days, but then you are overwriting your objects with the last iteration.

Instead you need to add each iteration to an output object (I call it `Out` here), then put your `data.frame` code inside the loop and use `rbind()` to append the output:

```
Out<-NULL  # initiate empty object
for (i in days){
  
  link = paste0("https://alrai.com/search?date-from=", days[i])
  
  readlink <- read_html(link)
  link_maxpagenumbers_full <- readlink %>%
    html_elements(".roboto-b") %>%
    html_text2()
  link_maxpagenumbers_cut <- str_extract_all(link_maxpagenumbers_full,'\\d{1,3}')
  
readlink <- read_html(link)

article_links <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".font-700") %>%
  html_attr("href")

link_title <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".font-700") %>%
  html_text2()

link_date <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".size-13")%>%
  html_text2()

link_pagesummary <- readlink %>%
  html_elements(".size-14") %>%
  html_text2()
    
alrai <- data.frame(article_links, link_title, link_date, link_pagesummary)  # create a data frame
Out<-rbind(Out,alrai) # add this iterations data to the output
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. The professor I am doing this for has mentioned creating an empty object and rbinding, but never explained that it was because of this issue of rewriting. Thank you so much! This worked.